# Accessing File from the Server

Tags: c#, wcf

I developed a WCF service and consuming to another application. In that service I have an xml file.

What is the way to access the file?

I have used the following code:

```
public string InsertData(string Name, string Email, string Message)
{
    string file = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("DataFile.xml");
    DataTable dtEmployee = ReadXML(file);
    // adding Employee Object values to datarow.
    DataRow dr = dtEmployee.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = Name;
    dr["Email"] = Email;
    dr["Message"] = Message;
    dtEmployee.Rows.Add(dr);
    dtEmployee.WriteXml(file);
    return "Success";
}
```

File exists on the same project. How can i access that file. You can get the idea from the following screenshot:

[image]

Currently the file is getting null.

[image]

Comment: Did you specify that the file should be ouputted on build? (Build action)

Comment: @RandRandom When i am running the service, the file shows the null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the below menioned code.

Add method name in your interface of service like

```
    [OperationContract]
    string GetXmlstring();
```

Implemetation of method look like

```
public string GetXmlstring()
    {
        var fileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName+"\\DataFile.xml");
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

call that method like

```
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client ss = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        var xmlstring=ss.GetXdoc();
```

Now `xmlstring` contain the xml string.

Comment: Where i'll use the ServiceReference1? It is not accessible in the service.

Comment: you have to use in DataServiceTestApp

Comment: There is a condition in my project that i do not have to use the cs file in the application, i have to use it by the js file

Comment: ok that means InsertData method you have written is in service ?

Comment: Yes, the InsertData method is created on the Service1.cs

Comment: string file=AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"\\DataFile.xml"";

Comment: Good Job..Happy coding.